# An efficient way to prepend a string to another format string using vsprintf

Tags: c, printf

I am using vsprintf to generate a string from a format and need to prepend a looked up prepend string before logging it.  The code below prints the format string but how would I prepend another string to that?  Ideally in a fairly efficient way.

Eg if I called like this:

```
LOG(SYSTEM1, DEBUG, "number=%d, string=%s\n", 1, "Hi");
```

I would see printed:

```
SYSTEM1    number=1, string=Hi
```

Code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define EMERGENCY       0 
#define ERROR           1 
#define WARN            2
#define INFO            3
#define DEBUG           4  

enum SubSystemID { SYSTEM1, SYSTEM2, SYSTEM3, SYSTEM4 };

void LOG(enum SubSystemID id, unsigned long severity, const char* format, ...) {
    static const char* chaTypes[] = { 
        "SYSTEM1", "SYSTEM2", "SYSTEM3", "SYSTEM4" };

    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vsprintf(buffer, format, args);

    // Code here to send a char* string to a logging system
    printf(buffer);

    va_end (args);
}
```

Comment: Why not use the final `printf` to do the concatenation? And the array should be `static const char * const chaTypes[]`, otherwise the table itself is not `const`.

Comment: @Olaf  That would be too easy.  Yet I suspect `printf(buffer);` is a placeholder for the real "send a char* string to a logging system".

Comment: @Olaf as suggested by chux, printf(buffer) is indeed a placeholder for sending string to a logging system

Comment: That makes your question even more unclear. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I believe the overall goal is to output the result of the `vsprintf()` to the output stream without the performance hit of a second call to `printf()`.  The simple answer is to call `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), stdout)` which doesn't perform any formatting, it just outputs to the file stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:-

```
strcpy (buffer, chaTypes [id]);
vsprintf (&buffer [strlen (buffer)], format, args);
```

or you could precalculate the strlen part making it an array of integers:-

```
static int [] lengths = null;

if (lengths == null)
{
  lengths = malloc (sizeof (int), sizeof chaTypes / sizeof chaTypes [0]);
  foreach string
    lengths [i] = strlen (chaTypes [i]);
}
```

Comment: Is `foreach string` pseudo code or some new flavor of C?

Answer (score 1):

Code could re-write the format.

```
// concatenate in some fashion.
char *prefix = chaTypes[id];  //  chaTypes[] must not contain %
size_t len1 = strlen(prefix);
size_t len2 = strlen(format) + 1;
char newformat[len1 + len2];
memcpy(newformat, prefix, len1);
memcpy(&newformat[len1], prefix, len2);

vsprintf(buffer, newformat, args);
```

Yet [@Skizz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35777027/2410359) `strcpy()` idea is hard to beat.

Comment: The problem I see with using malloc() and/or strcpy() is that vsprintf() already does this for you in place so you avoid the penalty of an extra copy.One copy to whatever memory allocated string you've made and then another from vsprintf() itself.

Comment: @Kelmar Concerning "using malloc() and/or strcpy()".  This answer does not use `malloc()` nor `strcpy()`.  Further, `vsprintf()` is not known to call `malloc()` so the comment about `malloc()` is unclear.  Further, copying the string is trivial in performance compared  to the sink-hole of processing that goes on with processing a format string.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct about the memory allocation.  

Still why go through all the effort of doing all the string copy yourself if vprintf() does this for you anyhow?

Comment: @Kelmar Assume that the write to the log can only be done once per `LOG()` call as that function may prepend/append data like log count, time-stamp, processor ID, etc.  So as OP asked to prepend into another (one) string.  Using Skizz `strcpy()` and passing an offset'd `buffer` is a good solutoin.  My answer offers another approach of altering the format.  In both cases **one** string is formed and then sent on to the logging system.

Comment: @Skizz  Okay, but your call to vsprintf() isn't to the logging system.  It is unclear to me that performing your own memory copies and trying to do the formatting yourself of a date, time, and whatever else would be any more or less efficient than calling vsprintf() to begin with.  The performance hit of calling that function is pretty huge regardless of what you do outside of it.  If speed is a concern with your logging then it would be best to try not to call vsprintf() at all if your log level is disabled.

Comment: @Skizz Just verified some things, and have written a quick test program to perform a bit of metrics gathering.  [This may not be the best test](http://pastebin.com/vut3pVtP), but in general the proposed use of `memcpy()` had about 100k to 200k less calls in a second on my Linux VM and calling `fwrite()` and `fvprintf()` directly.   However, disabling the logs by simulating a disabled log level yielded massive performance gains.  Your results may vary.

Comment: @Kelma  To whom are your previous 2 comments addressed? To Skizz, which should be under that answer or chux, which should use a different (at).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to avoid formatting I would use fwrite() and send it whatever file handle you want.  If you want to use some other facility then you probably want to have some sort of generic output string function and then pump your logging statements through that.

For example:

```
void writeLogString(const char *str, int len)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    OutputDebugStringA(str);
#else
    fwrite(str, sizeof(char), len, stdout);
#endif
}

void vlogf(enum SubSystemID id, unsigned long severity, const char *format, va_args args)
{
    const char *chaTypes[] = { "SYSTEM1", "SYSTEM2", "SYSTEM3", "SYSTEM4" };

    char buffer[256];
    int len = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, args);

    writeLogString(chaTypes[id], strlen(chaTypes[id]));
    writeLogString(" ", 1);
    writeLogString(buffer, len);
}

void logf(enum SubSystemID id, unsigned long severity, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vlogf(id, severity, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Generally speaking I would make sure my logging works first and foremost as it's usually pretty critical to debugging your applications.

If you are having a speed issue, then printf() is just going to kill the performance regardless of what you try and do.  If you really need to speed up your logging in a production environment you may want to consider using some macros to not even call the format function if that severity is disabled.

Edit: [A working example here with some tests](http://pastebin.com/vut3pVtP)